# Multiple ion-toggle doesn't switch separately

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was creating an ionic app, where I required a toggle switch to be controlled separately. But, unfortunately my code toggles all switches together on tapping any one switch. Can this be resolved and each toggle be controlled individually?

> app.ts file

```
toggleSwitch(switchName) {
    console.log(switchName + ' toggled');
    console.log('Toggle value=' + this.toggleValue);
  }
```

> app.html file

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let switch of switches">
              <ion-label>Switch Name: {{switch.Switch.name}}</ion-label>
              <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggleValue" (ionChange)="toggleSwitch(switch.Switch.name)"></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

[image: Glimpse of the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `ion-toggle` in the loop are bound to the same variable: `toggleValue`. Because of two way binding, changing one will reflect in all.

Depending on how you want to save the data, either have the value in the original `switch` array or in a separate one and set it in `ngModel`.

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="switch.value" (ionChange)="toggleSwitch(switch.Switch.name)"></ion-toggle>
```